# preg_match() fails when trying to match a "space double quote" pattern (on string queried from MSSQL DB)

Tags: php, sql-server, regex, pcre

Can you help me understand what's happening here?

I have this string queried from MSSQL DB

```
$string = 'Key Lesson: "<u>Part 1</u>';
```

See that space before the double-quote?  For some reason all three of these matching attempts fail:

```
<?php
if(preg_match('~Key Lesson: "<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1)

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:[[:blank:]]+"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1)

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:[[:space:]]+"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1)
?>
```

But these two work:

```
if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:\h"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1)

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:."<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1)
```

What in the world is that character in there? And how did it get in there?

My only guess, given that it's a double-quote and that the string is extracted from a MSSQL database, is that it has something to do with the data prep that's done when the data is either stored in the DB or when it's queried for use.  (I'm using the mssql_query() & mssql_fetch_array() PHP functions to get the data)

Comment: Can you please correct the malformed `"` in your code? I just want to confirm you've actually got parseable PHP eg `"~Key Lesson: "<u>Part 1</u>~i"` either needs escaping or outer single quotes

Comment: Your code seems fine, it's possible there's some invisible control characters or character encoding issue at hand.

Comment: Have you tried to get the ASCII char code `ord ( )` of that character? Is it _32_ or something else?

Comment: @EhsanT I still don't know what the character is. I was trying to figure out some way to contain it, but I just gave up and used \h anywhere that I had to match space characters. Not sure if I'll run into problems when trying to import the data into a MySQL DB.

Comment: @TJW Please use the function in [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812) and you can see what is really in your string and what character is really there. I doubt that for the space character you get the char-code of 32. But please give it a try and update us on the result by editing your post and adding the result to it...

Comment: @EhsanT Thanks a ton for finding that function for me! Just plain awesome that you would do that. I'll go back and try to find the record I was having trouble with. If I can find it I'll post and let you know what it reports for that character. Wow, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked with me without any issues. Try the following code, and check if it works with you:

```
<?php

$string = 'Key Lesson: "<u>Part 1</u>';  

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson: "<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1) echo 'OK 1 ';

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:[[:blank:]]+"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1) echo 'OK 2 ';

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:[[:space:]]+"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1) echo 'OK 3 ';

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:\h"<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1) echo 'OK 4 ';

if(preg_match('~Key Lesson:."<u>Part 1</u>~i', $string, $matches) == 1) echo 'OK 5 ';

?>
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/R1CeWy